# JavaScript CSS styling in IE

Tags: javascript, css, dom-events

JavaScript CSS styling not working in IE, it is working in Chrome and Mozilla.

This is my code:

```
document.ready=function() {
        var val = document.getElementById("registration_select").value;
        if(val =="Relay - Ultra, Standard and Sprint distances (Men / Women/ Mixed) - open to all Age-Groups & Juniors above 16"){            
        document.getElementById("register_right").style.display="block";
        }
        else{            
        document.getElementById("register_right").style.display="none";
        }

 registration_select.onchange=function(){
        var val = document.getElementById("registration_select").value;
        if(val =="Relay - Ultra, Standard and Sprint distances (Men / Women/ Mixed) - open to all Age-Groups & Juniors above 16"){            
        document.getElementById("register_right").style.display="block";
        }
        else{            
        document.getElementById("register_right").style.display="none";
        }
     }
};
```

This is my HTML

```
<select id="registration_select" name="Category">
<option value="category1">category1</option>
<option value="Relay - Ultra, Standard and Sprint distances (Men / Women/ Mixed) - open to all Age-Groups & Juniors above 16">Relay - Ultra, Standard and Sprint distances (Men / Women/ Mixed) - open to all Age-Groups & Juniors above 16</option>
</select>

<div id="register_right">

<h3>Team Mate Profile</h3>

</div>
```

And this is my CSS

```
#register_right{float:right;  display:none; width:49%;}
```

Please Help.

Comment: plz show the html also..and make sure there is no duplicate `id's` in your html.

Comment: Do not see any jquery here.

Comment: just a suggestion... javascript is case sensitive you are compairing a long string in if statememt ... so just convert left and right hand side to lowercase and then check whether they are equal or not.

Comment: Jquery has left the building. Your code has no jquery in it!

Comment: your thanks in advance is wasted! because question is not clear to us.

Comment: Can you please change the code that works for IE

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/89epLxao/ Check this. Working fine in IE10 and Chrome

Comment: What version of IE? You could try this to see if it makes a difference `var sel = document.getElementById("registration_select"), val = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;`

Comment: IE 9, Tried everything in the comments. But nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 jQuery(function($) {
        var val = document.getElementById("registration_select").value;

            if(val =="Relay - Ultra, Standard and Sprint distances (Men / Women/ Mixed) - open to all Age-Groups & Juniors above 16"){            
                document.getElementById("register_right").style.display="block";
            }
            else{            
                document.getElementById("register_right").style.display="none";
            }

            document.getElementById("registration_select").onchange=function(){
                var val = document.getElementById("registration_select").value;
                if(val =="Relay - Ultra, Standard and Sprint distances (Men / Women/ Mixed) - open to all Age-Groups & Juniors above 16"){            
                    document.getElementById("register_right").style.display="block";
                }
                else{            
                    document.getElementById("register_right").style.display="none";
                }
            }

    });
```

Comment: @AasimHussainKhan : in your code, registration_select was undefined.